# Does building over rooms render the old room inactive?

Tags: boss-monster

When you build a room over an existing room, is the existing room considered deactivated, or does it still effect game play?

For example if you build a Monster's Ballroom over Goblin Armory does the Ballroom count the Armory as a monster room, and does the Goblin Armory still have its ability, damage and /or treasure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you build over a room the old room is no longer in play and has no effect on the dungeon until all rooms that have been built over it have been destroyed and it is the top room again. When that happens ita normal rules are back in play.

Comment: That is what we finally figured must be the way it worked, but couldn't find anything that clarified it. Thanks.